# DateTime Comparison Precision

Tags: c#, datetime, comparison

I'm doing DateTime comparison but I don't want to do comparison at second, millisecond and ticks level. What's the most elegant way?

If I simply compare the DateTime, then they are seldom equal due to ticks differences.

Comment: I think there is no siver bullet here... It totally depends on your preference... Any way, Thanks for asking this question... I learnt many things from this Q.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that based on the selected answer, this question is wrong. You aren't asking to compare the *absolute time* up to the minute, you're asking to check if *elapsed time* is less than a certain threshold.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What about using a timespan.

```
if (Math.Truncate((A - B).TotalMinutes) == 0)
{
    //There is less than one minute between them
}
```

Probably not the most elegant way, but it allows for cases which are one second apart and yet have different days/hours/minutes parts such as going over midnight.

**Edit**: it occured to me that the truncate is unecessary...

```
if (Math.Abs((A - B).TotalMinutes) < 1)
{
    //There is less than one minute between them
}
```

Personally I think this is more elegant...

Comment: I think.. it should read as    if ((A - B).TotalMinutes <= 1)

Comment: Yeah you're right, I've removed the equals as well since the comment says less than.

Comment: For your edit to work, you need to call `Math.Abs` before checking if it is less than 1, because otherwise you could have a **huge** difference in the 2 `DateTime` values. For example `(DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10)).TotalMinutes` would be less than 1, but have 10 minutes total difference.

Comment: This solution can return `true` for different minutes of two different hours. I don't believe this answer is correct. Example: `DateTime A = new DateTime(2016, 10, 26, 10, 59, 40), B = new DateTime(2016, 10, 26, 11, 00, 20);`.

Answer (score 10):

One approach could be to create two new DateTimes from your values you want to compare, but ignore anything from the seconds on down and then compare those:

```
DateTime compare1 = new DateTime(year1, month1, day1, hour1, minute1, 0);
DateTime compare2 = new DateTime(year2, month2, day2, hour2, minute2, 0);

int result = DateTime.Compare(compare1, compare2);
```

I'd be the first to admit it's not elegant, but it solves the problem.

Comment: This solution is nice because it detects if it's the same minute (whereas some other solutions might return true for different minutes that are only seconds apart, e.g. 11:59:59 and 12:00:01). And, it should perform better than string based comparisons.

Comment: If you happen to be comparing by date, there's a shortcut to new DateTime(...). Just use foo.Date.

Answer (score 8):

Using a TimeSpan you get all the granularity you want :

```
DateTime dt1, dt2;
double d = (dt2 - dt1).TotalDays;
double h = (dt2 - dt1).TotalHours;
double m = (dt2 - dt1).TotalMinutes;
double s = (dt2 - dt1).TotalSeconds;
double ms = (dt2 - dt1).TotalMilliseconds;
double ticks = (dt2 - dt1).Ticks;
```

Comment: Testing shows a TimeSpan created from 2 equal DateTime values down to the same millisecond give all sorts of values > 1 for everything other than TotalMilliseconds.

Comment: @hoang I recant; I was incorrect.  I was only seeing that you can never compare the values directly; there will always be minute differences.

Comment: @hoang  Now I'm just confused.  I do see large differences.  DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now; DateTime d2 = new DateTime( d1.Year, d1.Month, d1.Day, d1.Hour, d1.Minute, d1.Second, d1.Millisecond ); TimeSpan diff = d2 - d1; Debug.Print( $"Days: {diff.TotalDays}" );

Comment: This is because there are a "few" ticks you don't take into account after the Milliseconds. Try this : DateTime d2 = new DateTime(d1.Ticks);

Answer (score 8):

```
public class DateTimeComparer : Comparer<DateTime>
{
    private Prescision _Prescision;

    public enum Prescision : sbyte
    {
        Millisecons,
        Seconds,
        Minutes,
        Hour,
        Day,
        Month,
        Year,
        Ticks
    }

    Func<DateTime, DateTime>[] actions = new Func<DateTime, DateTime>[]
        {
            (x) => { return x.AddMilliseconds(-x.Millisecond);},
            (x) => { return x.AddSeconds(-x.Second);},
            (x) => { return x.AddMinutes(-x.Minute);},
            (x) => { return x.AddHours(-x.Hour);},
            (x) => { return x.AddDays(-x.Day);},
            (x) => { return x.AddMonths(-x.Month);},
        };

    public DateTimeComparer(Prescision prescision = Prescision.Ticks)
    {
        _Prescision = prescision;
    }

    public override int Compare(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        if (_Prescision == Prescision.Ticks)
        {
            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }

        for (sbyte i = (sbyte)(_Prescision - 1); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            x = actions[i](x);
            y = actions[i](y);
        }

        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
new DateTimeComparer(DateTimeComparer.Prescision.Day).Compare(Date1, Date2)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this ComparerClass?

```
public class DateTimeComparer : Comparer<DateTime>
{
    private string _Format;

    public DateTimeComparer(string format)
    {
        _Format = format;
    }

    public override int Compare(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        if(x.ToString(_Format) == y.ToString(_Format))
            return 0;

        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

This can be used by

```
List.Sort(new DateTimeComparer("hh:mm"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert them to String format and compare the string with each other.

This also gives freedom to choose your comparison parameters, like only the time without the date, etc.

```
if (String.Format("{0:ddMMyyyyHHmmss}", date1) == String.Format("{0:ddMMyyyyHHmmss}", date2))
{
     // success
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea. However I'd find more elegant to write it like `date1.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") == date2.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss")`

Comment: This looks clean and simple, but it converts numbers to strings, then compares strings - it's inefficient compared to some of the other solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

I've written this to help myself:

```
    internal class ImpreciseCompareDate : IComparer<DateTime>
{
    private readonly double _Tolerance;

    public ImpreciseCompareDate(double MillisecondsTolerance)
    {
        _Tolerance = MillisecondsTolerance;
    }

    public int Compare(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        return Math.Abs((x - y).TotalMilliseconds) < _Tolerance ? 0 : x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

Tolerance can be set to (10d/3d) to account for SQL servers 1/300th of a ms. If tolerance is exceeded, delegate to default comparer.

Comment: The advantage to this approach is obviously the ability to set an arbitrary tolerance independent of the levels already provided by datetime (second, ms, etc.) being that SQL server tolerance does not break even on one of these. ie. 1/300th of a second.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to convert first by processing on ticks level with a simple (non-rounding) calculation:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
// 636340541021531973, 2017-06-26T06:08:22.1531973Z

var millisecondsPrecision = new DateTime(now.Ticks / 10000 * 10000, now.Kind);
// 636340541021530000, 2017-06-26T06:08:22.1530000Z

var secondsPrecision = new DateTime(now.Ticks / 10000000 * 10000000, now.Kind);
// 636340541020000000, 2017-06-26T06:08:22.0000000Z

var minutePrecision = new DateTime(now.Ticks / (10000000*60) * (10000000*60), now.Kind);
// 636340541000000000, 2017-06-26T06:08:00.0000000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

@ALZ's solution looks nice but it's too complicated and has a bug.
So I decided to combine it with @ChrisF's solution.

```
    public class DateTimeComparer : Comparer<DateTime>
    {
        public enum Precision
        {
            Years = 0,
            Months,
            Days,
            Hours,
            Minutes,
            Seconds,
            Millisecons,
            Ticks
        }

        private Precision _precision;

        public DateTimeComparer(Precision precision =  Precision.Ticks)
        {
            _precision = precision;
        }

        public override int Compare(DateTime x, DateTime y)
        {
            if (_precision == Precision.Ticks)
            {
                return x.CompareTo(y);
            }

            var xx = AssembleValue(x, _precision);
            var yy = AssembleValue(y, _precision);

            return xx.CompareTo(yy);
        }

        private static DateTime AssembleValue(DateTime input, Precision precision)
        {
            var p = (int)precision;
            var i = 1;
            return new DateTime(input.Year,
                                p >= i++ ? input.Month : 1,
                                p >= i++ ? input.Day : 1,
                                p >= i++ ? input.Hour : 0,
                                p >= i++ ? input.Minute : 0,
                                p >= i++ ? input.Second : 0,
                                p >= i++ ? input.Millisecond : 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution from my own code:

```
TimeSpan timeDifference = presentLastSavedDate.Subtract(previousLastSavedDate);
if (timeDifference.Seconds > 0)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, ALREADY_CHANGED_MSG);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have create a very fast compare functions to compare DateTime with different Precission. All are arithmetical calculations and no new object are created.

```
public enum DateTimeComparePrecision : long
{
    Millisecond  = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond,
    Second = TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond,
    Minute = TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute,
    Hour = TimeSpan.TicksPerHour,
    Day = TimeSpan.TicksPerDay,
}


public static bool DatesAreEqual(DateTime d1, DateTime d2, DateTimeComparePrecision Precision)
{
    return (d1.Ticks - (d1.Ticks % (long)Precision)) == (d2.Ticks - (d2.Ticks % (long)Precision));
}        


public static int DatesCompare(DateTime d1, DateTime d2, DateTimeComparePrecision Precision)
{
    long Day1 = (d1.Ticks - (d1.Ticks % (long)Precision));
    long Day2 = (d2.Ticks - (d2.Ticks % (long)Precision));

    if (Day2 > Day1) 
        return 1;            

    if (Day2 < Day1)            
        return -1;            

    return 0;
}
```

### How Ticks Transformed for the compare

```
DateTime NowIs = DateTime.UtcNow;
Console.WriteLine($"{NowIs:dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffffff}");

DateTime d1 = new DateTime((NowIs.Ticks - (NowIs.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond)));
Console.WriteLine($"{d1:dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffffff}");

d1 = new DateTime((NowIs.Ticks - (NowIs.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)));
Console.WriteLine($"{d1:dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffffff}");

d1 = new DateTime((NowIs.Ticks - (NowIs.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute)));
Console.WriteLine($"{d1:dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffffff}");

d1 = new DateTime((NowIs.Ticks - (NowIs.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerHour)));
Console.WriteLine($"{d1:dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffffff}");

d1 = new DateTime((NowIs.Ticks - (NowIs.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerDay)));
Console.WriteLine($"{d1:dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffffff}");
```

**output**

```
01 03 2022 12:51:26.7237323
01 03 2022 12:51:26.7230000
01 03 2022 12:51:26.0000000
01 03 2022 12:51:00.0000000
01 03 2022 12:00:00.0000000
01 03 2022 00:00:00.0000000
```