# problem with comparing two files based on datetime upto minute?

Tags: c#, linq

If i compare two files without rounding upto minute result for these queries

```
var queryList1Only3 = (from file in list1 select file).Except(list2, myFileCompare2);
var queryList1Only33 = (from file in list2 select file).Except(list1, myFileCompare2);
```

are

```
12/14/2010 4:14:10 PM     C:\xml\Tracker.xml
10/13/2010 3:00:27 PM      D:\xml\Tracker.xml
```

But if i round the datetime upto minute the result for queryList1Only3 is

```
   12/14/2010 4:14:10 PM     C:\xml\Tracker.xml
```

and second query returns nothing but empty because i have modified that `C:\xml\Tracker.xml` file only..and the other file is without changes...

and

```
public class FileCompareLastwritetime : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo>
        {
            public FileCompareLastwritetime() { }
            public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2)
            {
                return RoundToMinute(f1.LastWriteTime) == RoundToMinute(f2.LastWriteTime);
            }
            public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fi)
            {
               return RoundToMinute(fi.LastWriteTime).GetHashCode();
            }
        }


 public static DateTime RoundToMinute(DateTime time)
            {
                return new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, time.Day,
                                    time.Hour, time.Minute, 0, time.Kind);
            }
```

Any suggestion??

EDIT:

```
   IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
   IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Please refer to this link... You could get various options... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956748/datetime-comparison-precision/2956818

Comment: @The King:can you tell the problem in my code??

Comment: Can you add some detail? Where are the lists file1 and file2 coming from? Is that first set of results the result of both queries or just one? If so, which one?

Comment: @Rik Garner:Look at my edit..first set of results is the result of both queries

Comment: Is that enough or whether i have to add anything else???

Answer (score 1):

DateTime equals compares Ticks which can be slightly different when setting the values using time.Year, time.Month, etc.  The best DateTime truncation method I have found is the following:

```
///<summary>
/// Extension methods for DateTime class
///</summary>
public static class DateTimeExt
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Truncates a DateTime to a specified resolution.</para>
    /// <para>A convenient source for resolution is TimeSpan.TicksPerXXXX constants.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date">The DateTime object to truncate</param>
    /// <param name="resolution">e.g. to round to nearest second, TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond</param>
    /// <returns>Truncated DateTime</returns>
    public static System.DateTime Truncate(this System.DateTime date, long resolution)
    {
        return new System.DateTime(date.Ticks - (date.Ticks % resolution), date.Kind);
    }
}
```

Usage: myDateTime.Truncate(TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute) to truncate to minutes.  It does not round but neither does your example.